# BizTalk build using some tools

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013, biztalk-deployment, btdf

Is it possible to do Continuous integration.

We are using Power shell script to deploy BTDF packages. I found many resources to do continuous integration for BizTalk using TFS but is it possible to do continuous integration. Is there any resources available for the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, consider "continuous integration" is a pattern, not a thing.  So sure, you absolutely can do CI with BizTalk apps using a SVN.  Really, the code repository really isn't a factor.

So, if you are automatically, or at least very easily, doing a build-> deploy cycle with some tests, you're doing CI.  The specific underlying products doesn't really matter.

However, yes, CI with BizTalk and TFS is easier because of the tooling.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is perfectly feasible to use SVN for CI with BizTalk - I implemented such a solution back in 2008/9 using JetBrains TeamCity connected to SVN, utilising MSBuild scripts to perform the build, package and deployment to a test BizTalk environment. We then packaged the MSBuild scripts to perform the actual deploy to the various production environments.

If you're stuck with using SVN then I would seriously take a look at TeamCity (https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) and use a Powershell Build Runner to build / deploy etc. your project - for a high-level overview on using PS in TeamCity, take a look at http://www.jokecamp.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-use-teamcity-powershell-runner-to-automatically-deploy-website/.

As for SVN, you seriously need to take a look at using a more modern, feature-rich and vulnerability-free VCS Take a look at using something a little more modern such as Visual Studio Online (i.e TFS in the cloud - https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs.aspx) or Git (hosted through the myriad hosting providers, e.g. a private repo on https://github.com/)

Best of luck!

PS. I agree with @Johns-305 comments fully!